# Homework problem using strchr gives me unexpected output

Tags: c++, split, count, c-strings

I have to write a C program which outputs the number of words of a text, and on the next line, the words which begin and end either with a vowel or with a consonant.

For example:

```
input
La bacalaureat la proba de Informatica a fost un subiect cu un sir de caractere
```

```
output
15     
bacalaureat Informatica a fost subiect sir
```

Here's my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    char sir[100], copie[100];
    cin.get(sir, 100);
    strcpy(copie, sir);
    char* pch = strtok(sir, " ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        c++;
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    cout << c << endl;
    char* pch2 = strtok(copie, " ");
    while (pch2 != NULL)
    {
        if ((strchr("aeiouAEIOU", pch2[0]) && strchr("aeiouAEIOU", pch2[strlen(pch2)-1])) || (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", pch2[0] == NULL) && strchr("aeiouAEIOU", pch2[strlen(pch2)-1] == NULL)))
        {
            cout << pch2<<" ";
        }
        pch2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

But it gives me unexpected output. I get:

```
15
La bacalaureat la proba de Informatica a fost un subiect cu un sir de caractere
```

and I can't understand why. It's obviously because of that if, but it looks okay to me.

Can you help me fix my program? I don't understand what's happening tbh. Thanks.

Comment: If you have to "Write a C program" then why did you use C++ and tag the question with "c++"?

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, use `std::string` and `std::cin`.  The input will first skip whitespaces, then read characters until a whitespace is encountered.  Much easier than using character arrays.  Also, `std::string` will dynamically increase; no worrying about character array overflow or that dreaded nul terminating character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sub-expression used in if statement

```
strchr("aeiouAEIOU", pch2[0] == NULL) && strchr("aeiouAEIOU", pch2[strlen(pch2)-1] == NULL)
```

is wrong.

There must be

```
strchr("aeiouAEIOU", pch2[0]  ) == NULL && strchr("aeiouAEIOU", pch2[strlen(pch2)-1] ) == NULL
```

You could write the if statement much simpler the following way

```
if ( ( strchr( "aeiouAEIOU", pch2[0] ) == NULL ) == 
     ( strchr( "aeiouAEIOU", pch2[strlen(pch2)-1] ) == NULL ) )
```

But in any case creating a copy of the source string and using `strtok` is not a good approach.

It is better to use standard C function `strspn` and `strcspn` to extract words in a string without changing it.

You can store words that satisfy the condition in a vector.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "La bacalaureat la proba de Informatica "
                    "a fost un subiect cu un sir de caractere";

    const char *vowels = "aeiou";
    const char *delim = " \t";

    std::vector<std::pair<const char *, const char *>> v;
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( const char *p = s; *p != '\0'; )
    {
        p += std::strspn( p, delim );
        const char *q = p;

        if ( *q )
        {
            ++n;
            p += std::strcspn( p, delim );

            char c1 = std::tolower( ( unsigned char )q[0] );
            char c2 = std::tolower( ( unsigned char )p[-1] );

            if ( ( std::strchr( vowels, c1 ) == nullptr ) == 
                 ( std::strchr( vowels, c2 ) == NULL ) )
            v.emplace_back( q, p );              
        }
    }

    std::cout << n << '\n';
    for ( const auto &p : v ) std::cout.write( p.first, p.second - p.first ) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
15
bacalaureat Informatica a fost subiect sir
```

Comment: oh my god I can't believe I missed that lmao. I couldn't see that I didn't close the paranthesis. I'll accept your answer asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of your program using `strchr`, but using `std::istringstream` to break up the words:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

bool isvowel(char ch)
{
    return strchr("aeiouAEIOU",ch)?true:false;
}

bool isconsonant(char ch)
{
    return !isvowel(ch);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> sVect;
    int word_count = 0;
    std::string test = "La bacalaureat la proba de Informatica a fost un subiect cu un sir de caractere";
    std::istringstream strm(test);
    std::string word;
    while (strm >> word)
    {
        ++word_count;
        if ( (isvowel(word.front()) && isvowel(word.back())) ||
             (isconsonant(word.front()) && isconsonant(word.back())))
            sVect.push_back(word);     
    }
    std::cout << word_count << "\n";
    for (auto& s : sVect)
        std::cout << s << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
15
bacalaureat Informatica a fost subiect sir
```

Note that the test for vowel or consonant are placed in separate functions, making the comparison easier.

Also note the use of `front()` and `back()` of the `std::string` class to easily get the first and last character of each word instead of repeatedly calling `strlen` in the comparison.

Comment: I'll look into your alternative too. Thanks a lot for your time.